# Does engineering require extensive math?

Tags: mathematics

I hope this question is okay for here. I've been interested in engineering for quite some time, but havent really ever had the motivation to do anything about it. I took a small principles of engineering class last year but it wasn't very serious. We kind of just messed around with 3D printing and computer games. 
I'm not very good at math. It's not so much that I can't do it, but I just forget it and am often too scatterbrained to focus and get it done. I've also missed years of math and so lack a lot of basic knowledge. 
In my class, we were mostly given formulas to follow for simple problems, and I didn't really run in to too much difficulty. But I'm wondering, in the world of engineering, when you're actually out in the field, let's say mechanical/civil particualry, how much math do you use?
I've always felt sort of held back from getting involved because I worry I'm not "smart enough"

Comment: Depending on the field of engineering you engage in & what you do, you may not use much complicated math after graduation, *but*, while studying to get your qualifications you will definitely be required to study math & some if it will be complex. There is no way around this! Engineers need to be qualified to a certain standard before they can call themselves engineers & before they can work as engineers.

Comment: @Fred it's always complex (sqrt(-1).... :)

Comment: Career and education advice is off-topic for the site.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ok, but motivating people to take engineering has to be good no?

Comment: In a lot of ways, math is not something that you will *do* as an engineer.   The computers will do the actual calculations.  Math is more of a language that is used to express ideas. So if you don't understand the language, you won't understand what your computer, your fellow engineers, or your college professors are trying to tell you. In a way, the calculus and linear algebra classes you will take the 1st two years of college are just teaching you the language that your 3rd and 4th year classes will be taught in.  If you don't understand the language, you'll never understand the class

Comment: @SolarMike - I agree with what you're saying, but we need to be mindful of what tools we have to solve different problems.  Questions like this would easily fall into the old close category of "primarily opinion based."  Doesn't mean it's a *bad* question.  It's not bad, and it's actually a good question.  But subjective, discussion based questions don't work in the StackExchange Q&A model.  That's why it's off-topic.  The chat room would be a better venue, although I will note that the OP doesn't have sufficient reputation to use chat.

Comment: @DanielKiracofe as for not doing math when you are an engineer - I have spent several evenings doing design (volume , stroke) and stress calcs for my son's project thar he has to make : an hydraulic bearing press all on paper with my trusted hp calculator (24sx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most fields of engineering may need integration, diferentiation, laplace transforms and also trig, solid body rotations etc

However I don't like math but still managed to complete - if you like engineering or are motivated by it then you will be ok.